# Makefile to get source files in multiple subdirectories

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, g++

I am creating a custom Makefile to to build a C++ Linux application. I have my cpp source files in a folder called *src* on the same level as the Makefile. So far I have been able to build my object files with the following :

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Now my project is starting to get a bit more complicated and I want subdirectories within *src* , such as *src/common* , and also, not every file is a *cpp* file now but also a *c* file.

I guess having a separate Makefile for each subdirectory is the best way but I am trying to keep this simple for now with just one Makefile.

I tried the following but doesn't work

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/common/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/common/%.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I could have the Makefile do a `shell find` to find all cpp and c files but also trying to avoid this.

I'd appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: The "simpler" solution usually is the nested makefiles. Many smaller files are still easier to manage than one behemoth file. But I'd go further and say forget that and use a build system like cmake or meson instead.

Comment: Variants of [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/08/26/makefile-c-projects/) also work fairly well in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/common/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/common/%.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
```

cannot work; what it says that if make wants to build some file `$(OBJ_DIR)/XXX.o` and there is no explicit rule, then *if and only if* **ALL** the prerequisites `$(SRC_DIR)/XXX.cpp`, `$(SRC_DIR)/common/XXX.cpp`, **and** `$(SRC_DIR)/common/XXX.c` exist or can be created by make, then the rule will match.

If the same target could be built from multiple different prerequisites you *must* create multiple rules, one per prerequisite.

Also, it doesn't make sense to compile both C files (`.c`) and C++ files (`.cpp`) using the same recipe.  C++ compilers use the variables `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` and C compilers use the variables `CC` and `CFLAGS`.

As for avoiding `find`, you can't avoid informing make what files you want to be compiled, in some manner.  You either have to list them in your makefile explicitly, or else use some method to generate them dynamically.  There's no way around this.  You don't have to use `find` if you don't want to; for example if you know that all the files will be either one or two directories down you could use `wildcard`, like:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/*.c $(SRC_DIR)/*/*.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/*/*.c)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to Make. I then had the following line after it which described the object files    OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o) . How would this then be modified to take into account all the cpp and c files found and not just those cpp files in src ?

Comment: Instead of that I recommend something like `OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRC))))`